# How to reaload Dropdown control In this way..please guide

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 aspx pages with C# code behind. Page one have 4 text boxes , one drop down and 2 buttons. Out of 2 buttons one if for appearing the second page as Popup ( as per system requirement. I could use here Ajax popup control , but requirement is different). So my page 2 has text box and button . on click of button of page2 textbox value will go in the database. and page will close. ok ? but same time, dropdown on the page1 should be fill come with fill up the records without refreshing the page1.some how the values in 4 textboxes should be there in textboxes... i tried on my best to elaborate problem.please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use AJAX to populate the drop down list, which you can do using a web service.  Another problem with this is that if you use the standard ASP.NET DropDownList control, and modify the list on the client, you may get an error because the dropdownlist expects the list provided to it from the previous load.

Alternatively, when the user closes page 2, it could call a method on page 1 that calls __doPostBack to force a page postback in page 1, so you could use server code to populate page 1.

A separate page is going to add to the challenges, it would be a lot easier to leverage teh AJAX popup IMHO.

HTH.

Comment: how to call method from parent page code behind in child page code behind

Comment: I don't believe you can from the server; from the client-side in JS, you can access the opened window I believe using window.opener.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have 2 pages Page1 and Page2. Clicking on a button from Page1 takes you to a popup page Page2. Then on submit of Page2 you need to refresh DropdownList on Page1 but you need PartialPostback instead of FullPagePostback.

If that is the case. You can javascript to do partialpostback:
http://www.asp.net/%28S%28ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg%29%29/learn/ajax-videos/video-172.aspx

edit:
To call a method from popup page you need to access method of parent page like: parent.RefreshDropDown();

Reagards.

Comment: Yes Shoaib u r getting my problem really. I will follow ur link soon.

Comment: but i can not understand ur edit section. can u please explain it? I seems it is the solution for me

Comment: if you are opening a popup window using javascript. Then in order to call some method on parent window, you will have use parent.RefreshDropDown() where parent is javascript object to get refrence to parent browser window and RefreshDropDown is a javascript method on parent page which contains logic to do partial postback to refresh dropdown.

Comment: Still not getting Shoaib.please guide me.

Comment: how to call method from parent page code behind in child page code behind